# Compare two columns and paste it in third column code not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two columns with below data:

```
DATA_TYPE   DATA_TYPE     Result
VARCHAR2    VARCHAR2      1
NUMBER      NUMBER        1
VARCHAR2    NUMBER        1
```

I am using below code to do the comparison for the two columns but the result should be  `1,1,0` but the result I am getting is `1,1,1`.

Check the below code and tell me what's my mistake.

```
For j = 2 To Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3").Cells(j, 2).Value = Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3").Cells(j, 11).Value Then
       Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3").Cells(j, 20).Value = "1"
    Else
       Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3").Cells(j, 20).Value = "0"
    End If
Next J
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What columns are your data in? Make sure they're in `B`, and `K`.  Edit: Do you need VBA for this though?

Comment: Seems you are using Access Database Table,, and the shown examples are Data type,,, so tell us are you trying to compare Data type or what??

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can use a formula for this, no VBA needed:

```
=INT($B2=$K2)
```

Or, in VBA:

```
Sub t2()
Dim j As Long, lastRow As Long
lastRow = Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 2 To lastRow
    With Workbooks("Compare_Sheets").Worksheets("Temp3")
        .Cells(j, 20).Value = Evaluate(Abs(Int(.Cells(j, 2).Value = .Cells(j, 11).Value)))
    End With
Next j
End Sub
```